# A List, anyone can answer

Tags: java, list, collections

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); // final list
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // l is list
    List<Integer> m = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //  m is list
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3); // list l 

    m.add(4);
    m.add(5);
    m.add(6); // list m 

    temp.addAll(l); // add l to temp
    list.add(temp);
    System.out.println("temp: "+temp);
    System.out.println("list: "+list);


    temp.addAll(m); // add m to temp1
    list.add(temp);
    System.out.println("temp: "+temp);
    System.out.println("list: "+list);
}
```

the result is

```
temp: [1, 2, 3]
list: [[1, 2, 3]]
temp: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

I think it should be:

```
temp: [1, 2, 3]
list: [[1, 2, 3]]
temp: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

why the last list is `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`?

Comment: where is temp1 defined?

Answer (score 1):

I rename your temp1 to temp in order to get compiled correctly.

This is because when you first execute "list.add(temp);"

list gets a reference to temp. So when the content of temp is changed, the content of list also gets changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); // final list
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // l is list
    List<Integer> m = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //  m is list
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.add(3); // list l 

    m.add(4);
    m.add(5);
    m.add(6); // list m 

    temp.addAll(l); // add l to temp1
    list.add(temp); // list now references to temp. So when the content of temp is changed, the content of list also gets changed.
    System.out.println("temp: "+temp);
    System.out.println("list: "+list); 


    temp.addAll(m); // add m to temp. The content of temp is changed, so does the content of list
    list.add(temp); 
    System.out.println("temp: "+temp);
    System.out.println("list: "+list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `list` list ends up with two references to the same list (`temp`). You can achieve the desired behavior by creating a second temporary list, adding the contents of `temp` to it, then adding 4, 5, and 6 to it, then adding that temporary list to `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is no temp1 variable in the code, it is the same as temp.
You are surprised by the fact that after adding "temp" to the "list" in the first time, the content of this first element was changed when you change temp. What you are missing is that "list" is an list of *references*, so its first element is a *reference* to "temp", not a copy of its content. Hence, whenever "temp" changes, this will be reported in the printout, even if the content of ""list" is not changed.

You can examine this behavior by adding something, say "100" to temp "just before printing, without changing "list". You will see that 100 will appear in the printout.

Comment: Thanks very much, I know the meaning of "list of references".

Comment: @JZHOU Welcome. But then dont see what was the problem. :)